# Elasticsearch Giving Incorrect Result When Using "must_not" operator alongwith "must" Operator

Tags: elasticsearch

Query Example -

> ```
>     GET /beta/user/_search?routing=1&q=_id:54e5dc4817cf03cbbbe490e5
> {
>    "from":0,
>    "size":1,
>    "filter":{
>       "and":[
>          {
>             "query":{
>                "nested":{
>                   "path":"event",
>                   "query":{
>                      "bool":{
>                         "must":[
>                            {
>                               "match":{
>                                  "event.name":"e1"
>                               }
>                            },
>                            {
>                               "match":{
>                                  "event.count":"4"
>                               }
>                            }
>                         ]
>                      }
>                   }
>                }
>             }
>          },
>          {
>             "query":{
>                "nested":{
>                   "path":"event",
>                   "query":{
>                      "bool":{
>                         "must_not":{
>                            "match":{
>                               "event.name":"e2"
>                            }
>                         }
>                      }
>                   }
>                }
>             }
>          }
>       ]
>    }
> }
> ```

I am having problems with the above query when I tried to use "must_not" and "must" operator in a single query. Any help will be highly appreciated.

The above query has an event called "e1" where I'm trying to use must operator and also "must_not" operator with event called  "e2".

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible with just a nested query (or nested filter).  The problem is that documents are evaluated one doc at a time.  Internally, Elasticsearch stores nested documents as independent Lucene documents.  The root object becomes one Lucene doc, and each subsequent nested doc becomes its own Lucene doc.

This is how they maintain their relationship between fields without interacting with other nested documents.  [More details here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html)

When a query is being evaluated, it iterates over each nested document one-by-one.  The query can only "see" the values within that single nested doc.  This means it only knows about one set of `event.name` and `event.count` at a time, and is unable to match a `must` against nested doc #1 and a `must_not` against nested doc #2.

The workaround is to denormalize the nested data back into the root object.  This will allow you to check the denormalized "bag of values" for the terms you `must` and `must_not` include.  For example:

Create a new index...notice that we add ["include_in_root"](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html#_mapping) for the nested mapping

```
PUT /nestedtest/
{
    "mappings": {
        "test" : {
            "properties" : {
                "event" : {
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "include_in_root":true,
                    "properties": {
                        "name" : {"type": "string" },
                        "count"  : {"type": "integer" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Index some docs:

```
POST /nestedtest/test/
{
    "event": [
        {
            "name": "e1",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "e2",
            "count": 2
        }
    ]
}

POST /nestedtest/test/
{
    "event": [
        {
            "name": "e1",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "e3",
            "count": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Now execute a search.  This query is a `bool` which contains two must clauses:

- First must is the `nested` query.  This checks to make sure the nested doc has correct name and count
- Second must is a `bool` which makes sure at least one nested doc has `name: e1` and that no docs have `name: e2`

The final query looks like:

```
GET /nestedtest/test/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "event",
                  "query": {
                     "bool": {
                        "must": [
                           {
                              "match": {
                                 "event.name": "e1"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "match": {
                                 "event.count": "1"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "match": {
                           "event.name": "e1"
                        }
                     }
                  ],
                  "must_not": [
                     {
                        "match": {
                           "event.name": "e2"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

And it returns just the doc we are interested in:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {...},
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1.5155444,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "nestedtest",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "AUus7jbcS8gWlP4VLwGZ",
            "_score": 1.5155444,
            "_source": {
               "event": [
                  {
                     "name": "e1",
                     "count": 1
                  },
                  {
                     "name": "e3",
                     "count": 3
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you zach . I have some more question about elasticsearch nested object. can you guide me?